# Python Airflow custom sensor - which methods to implement

Tags: python, class, inheritance, airflow, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to write a custom sensor that inherits BaseSensorOperator and SSHOperator. in the sensor body I override `poke` and `execute` method.

```
  class mysensor (BaseSensorOperator,SSHOperator):
      template_fields = ("my_param")
      def __init__ (
          self,
          my_param = None,
          *args,
          **kawags):
      self.my_param = my_param
      super().__init__(
          command = "some bash command",
          ssh_conn_id = "some connection"
          *args,
          **kwargs)

def poke(self, context):
    ... (implemented poke)
def execute():
    ...(implemented execute)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom sensors are required to implement only the `poke` function. You should not override the `execute` function (unless you really know what you are doing). The execute function is implemented in `BaseSensorOperator` and that is what gives sensors their capabilities.

In your case you should not use `SSHOperator`, you should use `SSHHook` directly.

Your Sensor should look like:

```
from airflow.providers.ssh.hooks.ssh import SSHHook

class Mysensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    ...

    def poke(self,context):
      hook = SSHHook(...)
      # add your sensor logic here
```